# Changing task picture on Recents Screen in Android?

Tags: android, screen, task

It looks like the "recents" screen in Android phones takes a snapshot of a previously running app.  Is there any way to control what picture shows up here?

[image: Valid XHTML]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ActivityStack (lives in ActivityManagerService), SystemService save bitmap images when activity goes pause state.

see https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/services/java/com/android/server/am/ActivityStack.java and look screenshotActivities() method.

And there is no way to modify activity screenshot in recent apps list with public SDK api.

If you can modify android platform source, hack ActivityStack or WindowManagerService.